# jQuery opacity on hover

Tags: jquery

Please, help to rewrite this jQuery function:

```
$(".gallery dt a img").fadeTo("fast", .7);
$(".gallery dt a").hover(function () {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1)
},
function () {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast", .7)
});
```

Here is a html:

```
<dl class="gallery">
    <dt><a href="#"><img /></a></dt>
    <dd><a href="#">text</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Image appears (opacity: 1) when I hover a link in `<dt>` tag, how can I change this, to make image appear when I hover a links in both `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags?

**Nobody knows?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$('.gallery-small dl:children a')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think seth has the right selector for the hover, but in the hover I think you'd need a reference to the image itself instead of using `$(this)`.  Maybe something like:

```
var img = $(".gallery-small dt a img");
img.fadeTo("fast", .7);
$('.gallery-small dl:children a').hover(function() {
    img.fadeTo("fast", 1)
},
function() {
    img.fadeTo("fast", .7)
});
```

Comment: Do you know where it is breaking?  Perhaps it is the selectors?  Do you have a parent of <dl> with a class name of `gallery-small`?  What does this get you: `alert($(".gallery-small").length);`?

Comment: Do you get any opacity effects to work at all?  Or is it just when hovering that it doesn't work?

Comment: its seems to give nothing, no opacity and no effects. You can try it yourself

Comment: That's why I'm a bit confused.  I was able to get it working in FF 3.5 with the code I have above.  What type of image (png, jpg, etc) are you using and what browser?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want the image to appear when you hover over either the image, or the text associated with it. Is that correct? If so, this solution should work for you:

```
$(".gallery dt a img").fadeTo("fast", .7);
$(".gallery a").hover(function () {
    $(this).closest("dl").children("dt").children("img").fadeTo("fast", 1)
},
function () {
    $(this).closest("dl").children("dt").children("img").fadeTo("fast", .7)
});
```

This can probably be simplified further, if anyone has any ideas throw 'em out there.